# How to use other servlets service in another servlet?

Tags: java, http, servlets, web, request

I need to forward/craft request to another servlet from other servlet's service method manually. This servlet which calls another servlet, should extract the data from other servlet's response and send it's own response to client. How to achieve this kind of functionality?

`Client <-----> Servlet1 <-----> Servlet2`

I know it's bad design, but due the circumstances we have to introduce the functionality of Servlet2 to Servlet1

Comment: What about `response.sendRedirect();`.

Comment: Yes you can  achieve either by using Request Dispatcher's Forward or Include methods (available with `request` object) or Send Redirect method(available with `response` object). `ServletContext`  is also one of the ways to acheive `servlet` collaboration because it is the one which provides the information of all the servlets.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use HttpServletResponseWrapper and override its getOutputStream Method.

`CustomHttpServletResponseWrapper` and `CustomServletOutputStream` are implementation for this.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper;

public class CustomHttpServletResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
    private ServletOutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private CustomServletOutputStream os;

    public CustomHttpServletResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        super(response);
    }

    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        if (writer != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("getWriter() has already been called on this response.");
        }

        if (outputStream == null) {
            outputStream = getResponse().getOutputStream();
            os = new CustomServletOutputStream(outputStream);
        }

        return os;
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("getOutputStream() has already been called on this response.");
        }

        if (writer == null) {
            os = new CustomServletOutputStream(getResponse().getOutputStream());
            writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, getResponse().getCharacterEncoding()), true);
        }

        return writer;
    }

    @Override
    public void flushBuffer() throws IOException {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.flush();
        } else if (outputStream != null) {
            os.flush();
        }
    }

    public byte[] getContent() {
        if (os != null) {
            return os.getContent();
        } else {
            return new byte[0];
        }
    }

}
```

customServletOutputStream.java

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.WriteListener;

public class CustomServletOutputStream extends ServletOutputStream {

      private OutputStream outputStream;
        private ByteArrayOutputStream content;

        public CustomServletOutputStream(OutputStream outputStream) {
            this.outputStream = outputStream;
            this.content = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            outputStream.write(b);
            content.write(b);
        }

        public byte[] getContent() {
            return content.toByteArray();

}

        @Override
        public boolean isReady() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void setWriteListener(WriteListener writeListener) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
}
```

your Main class:
use `RequestDespetcher.include()` to redirect request to s2 and pass `CustomHttpServletResponseWrapper`.

```
 @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/s1")    
public String s1(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception{
         RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/oauth2/s2");
         CustomHttpServletResponseWrapper wrappedResponse = new CustomHttpServletResponseWrapper(res);
         rd.include(req, wrappedResponse);
         wrappedResponse.flushBuffer();
        byte[] result = wrappedResponse.getContent();
        System.out.println("result of servlet 2 "+new String(result));
    // here you got the result of servlet 2. manipulate it as you want. 

        return new String(result);
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/s2")
    public String s2(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){
        return "hello from s2";
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work either, as the response of S1 will to be calculated from the response of S2

Comment: @TuomasToivonen, modified the answer according your comment.

Comment: Unfortunately our project have older Java Platform which doesn't support HttpServletResponseWrapper. This seems like a decorator pattern, so maybe I can implement it myself. Thanks for the detailed answer anyway, I have to test this on my personal project.

Comment: you're welcome. I am wondering how you will achieve it without  HttpServletResponseWrapper, only this class provides the Implementation of HttpServletResponse. Post your answer if you solve it without HttpServletResponseWrapper. all the best.

Comment: And it will definitely work on your personal project. I have tested  before posting it here. :D

Comment: I implemented the HttpServletResponseWrapper myself, it just a wrapper which delegates  to contained HttpServletResponse. However, the RequestDispatcher doesn't seem to be working, getOutputStream and getWriter are never called. I can't step through the include method as source is not included.

Comment: RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("path of s2"). add correct path here.

Comment: It actually dispatched the request correctly but S2 threw exception, as it expected different request query string. so rather than forwarding request, I should somehow craft a new request object with same session and authentication headers/cookies as original request, but change some parameters. This is going very complex and smells like an anti pattern